# Combinatorics (discrete math course) help

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

problem 1:
you have 4 balls with different weights and 6 drawers stacked on top of each other.
how many ways are there to organize the balls such that the top drawer will have exactly 1 ball and the bottom drawer will have at least 1 ball?

problem 2:
from a group of 5 women and 6 men you need to choose a council made of a ceo, vp, cto, cfo.
in how many ways can you do that such that the ceo is a women and the oldest of the men will be in the council?

problem 3:
given a triangle on the plane; on each of its edges are 5 points that are not on the vertices.
how many triangles can be created when each of their vertices are on the points stated?

thx for your help,

Comment: Can you please give some clarity on the problem 3. "... when each of their vertices are on the points stated??"

Comment: you can create triangles from connecting 3 points on the edges of the described triangle with 15 points on its edges. notice the 3 points cant be on the same edge obviously..

Answer (score 1):

1) see the answer of @Rajkumar.

2) $5\times 3\times 9\times 8$.

Factor $5$ corresponds with the number of choices for the ceo. Factor $3$ with the number of duties that can be given to the oldest man. Then $9$ persons are left for $2$ duties, leading to $9\times 8$ possibilities.

3) $5^3+3\times\binom{5}{2}\times10$.

If the $3$ vertices are on $3$ different edges then there are $5^3$ possibilities.
Looking at triangles having $2$ vertices on the same edge there are $3\times\binom{5}{2}\times10$ possibilities. Factor $3$ corresponds with the choice of the edge with $2$ vertices. Factor $\binom{5}{2}$ with the choice of these $2$ vertices, and factor
$10$ with the choice of the third vertex.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**:
One ball should be in top drawer, so choosing one ball from 4 in 4 ways.
The other 3 calls can be arranged in 5 drawers in 3^5 ways.
But bottom should posses atleast one ball. So from 3^5 remove (number of ways 3 balls can be arranged in middle 4 drawers).

i.e. 4 * (3^5 - 3^4)
[Modified based on the inputs from [drhab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/75923/drhab)]

**Problem 2**:
Choosing CEO ( one woman from a group of 5 ) in 5 ways.
Oldest among men will be in the council in 1 way.
Remaining 2 could be from other 4 women & 5 men, i.e. from 9 in 9C2 ways.

So ans is = 5 * 1 * 9C2.

Comment: on 1): the balls have different weight, so they are distinguishable. That's why factor $4$ for the ball in the upper drawer is okay, but for the same reason the other factor ($5C3-4C3$) is not okay.

Comment: You mean to say, It should be (5P3-4P3)?

Comment: No. It should be $3^5-3^4$.

Comment: U r right. Thanks.